# Is there an Event that fires when any other event is triggered?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to measure the time it takes for any event (like ondrag, ondrop, onclick, ...) to be executed. Since I have a lot of potential events that could be fired in my code, I am looking for a simple solution to measure execution time. I only need this functionality in development, which is why I'd prefer a way without simply calling a method each time an event triggers.

So I am basically looking for an event which fires each time any other event triggers and wraps the fired event in a way that enables me to measure it's execution time.

Comment: If you only want to track the execution time, would the Chrome Dev Consoles Performance Tab be what you are looking for? It has a Event Log that gives a detailed list of all events and their executions times.

Comment: Yes thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for! Is there something similar for Firefox? I want to compare the execution time difference in each browser.

Comment: Firefox has a similar feature accessed by Shift+F5, however I have not used it before so I can not say if it has the same info for Events. Edit: Yup does have it: https://i.imgur.com/09wWWPl.png

Comment: Auch Deutscher ;) dankeschön!